# knob of propane tank was stuck

Tags: tools, appliances, oven, propane

I used the grill last year, and am planning to replace the propane tank. However, I found that I could not turn the knob. I marked the knob with red color in the following figure. I guess it maybe because it is stuck since I have not used it for so long. May I know are there any tools to turn this knob? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Unlike older style valves that loosened clockwise, these newer connections loosen counterclockwise when standing behind the regulator and facing the tank. Are you turning in that direction?

Comment: I tried both direction

Comment: I've never seen a BBQ-style propane tank that loosens clockwise. The plastic nut should loosen counter-clockwise when looking towards the tank outlet.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a pair of [Tongue-and-groove pliers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-and-groove_pliers), just be careful not to crank too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be VERY careful about trying any sort of tool unless you are sure the tank is 100%, absolutely empty. The risk of shearing the valve off the top of the tank is nontrivial, and if there's any pressure that can be seriously dangerous. Personally I'd be inclined to drag the whole grill to someplace that sells tanks and see if you can persuade them to help you with this.

Failing that... A plumber's strap wrench is the best tool I can think of. But I say again, I'm nervous about suggesting anything that could significantly increase the leverage applied to this.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, I had already turned the air valve to close. Should that be OK? The tank itself is pretty full, since I just used one time after buying it.

Comment: "The risk of shearing the valve off the top of the tank is nontrivial", meaning snapping the valve off entirely is a risk. Admittedly a small risk, but present none the less.

Comment: Please don't refer to flammable gasses as "air", it sets up a mindset that can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread and the OP should have found a solution or have totally given up. I recently faced the same issue. I do not have a plier at hand as mentioned by Tester101. What I did was to use a hammer and a flat screw driver. Put the screw driver head against a grove on the knob. Carefully knock on the screw driver with the hammer. The stuck knob went off quite easily.